# Can not run spring boot application using maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

Cannot run spring boot application using maven. When I run command mvn spring-boot:run I receive: `Could not find or load main class src.main.java.com.linkedinSearch.api.SearchApplication`, but in the pom.xml I write where is the main class using that example:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>src.main.java.com.linkedinSearch.api.SearchApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I have this project structure:

```
pom.xml
-src.main.java.linkedinSearch.api
--SearchApplication.java
--config
--controller
--exception
--model
--repository
--security
--service
```

I expected to run my application using spring boot and maven. But now that it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can remove

```
<configuration>
    <mainClass>src.main.java.com.linkedinSearch.api.SearchApplication</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

This is not necessary.

But if the package name of the mainClass is wrong.

It must not include the file structure src/main/java so it would simply be:

```
com.linkedinSearch.api.SearchApplication
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the normally generated project directory structure, which I believe you are, then this line:

```
<mainClass>src.main.java.com.linkedinSearch.api.SearchApplication</mainClass>
```

should be changed to:

```
<mainClass>com.linkedinSearch.api.SearchApplication</mainClass>
```

The `src/main/java` directory structure is not part of the package name.